# ADALjs communication to WebAPI causes token refresh but no request to WebAPI

Tags: cordova, asp.net-web-api, adal

I've been trying to get AdalJS to work on a Cordova/phonegap project.
I'm trying to make an api request to a webapi (that supports ADAL auth) but I only see a request for token refresh happening but no actual api request.

I see the following in the javascript console when I try to make a request to webapi after being logged in to the app and trying to do a get to the webapi:

```
renewToken is called for resource:https://mytentantid.onmicrosoft.com/webapiclientid
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFrame
Renew token Expected state: <token here>|https://mytentantid.onmicrosoft.com/webapiclientid
Navigate url:https://login.windows.net/mytenantid.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=<id here>8&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenantid.onmicrosoft.com%2FWebApiclientID&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebapiurl.azurewebsites.net&state=fc37b890-904d-4734-8f49-7ae1d79345a3%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fmytenantid.onmicrosoft.com%2FwebAPIclientID&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.0
Navigate to:https://login.windows.net/mytenantid.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=<client id token>8&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwebapiclientid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebapiurl.azurewebsites.net&state=<token>%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fmytenant.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwebapiclientid&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.0&prompt=none&login_hint=myaccount%40outlook.com&domain_hint=outlook.com&nonce=<nonce here>
LoadFrame: adalRenewFrame
HTML1300: Navigation occurred
File: about:blank (seems to navigate to a blank iframe)
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFrame
LoadFrame: adalRenewFrame
HTML1300: Navigation occurred
File: mywebapiurl.azurewebsites.net
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFrame
```

Definition for Adaljs in app.config:

```
    var localUri = window.location.href;
    var redirectUri = "https://mywebapiurl.azurewebsites.net";



    var config = {
        tenant: "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",
        clientId: '<client-id-of-mobile-app>',
        endpoints: {
            "https://mywebapiurl.azurewebsites.net/": "https://mytentantname.onmicrosoft.com/webAPIclientURI"
        },
        postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://www.google.com',
        extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
        localLoginUrl: '/login',
        displayCall: function (url) {
            var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=no');
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {
                if ((event.url).indexOf(redirectUri) === 0) {
                    ref.close();
                    window.location.href = event.url.replace(redirectUri + "/", localUri);
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        },
        cacheLocation: "localStorage"
    };

    if (localUri.indexOf("http://") !== 0 && localUri.indexOf("https://") !== 0) {
        config.redirectUri = redirectUri;
    }

    adalProvider.init(config, $httpProvider);
```

My webapi config settings:

```
<appsettings>
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="mytentantid.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:Audience" value="<api client uri>" />
</appsettings>
```

Startup.auth.cs:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
               new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
               {
                   Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                   Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
               });

        }
```

The API is running on Azure websites and is reachable by browser. When I do the get request I only see the token refresh but not the actual api request.
The Mobile app has permissions to use the webapi in AAD config.

Is there something wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints in the config are used for CORS API requests. It looks like you are trying to access api that is also hosting your page. You should remove the endpoints from the config.

Comment: It is a CORS request.  The app is running in cordova on android, iOS and wp8.1 and the api is on azure websites. The fact that the redirect uri is the same as the api url is due to the fact that the redirect uri must be a valid url.

Comment: I've been able to debug somewhat further. I've ran the code in a local website from visual studio in IE and I see this in the console: "Returned id_token not parseable". What does this mean?

Comment: Nvm doesn't work in cordova since iframes are not working properly.